# How adding property to function is different from adding to function constructor

Tags: javascript

How adding properties  to "new add().city" and "add().city"
    is different.

```
function add()
{
  this.name = 'suresh';
   this.lastname = 'kumar';
 }

  var b  =  new add();
  b.city = 'coimbatore';   

 add.city = 'coimbatore'     // how this is different from a above statement
```

Comment: Are you asking about `add.city` vs `add().city` now?

Comment: Well, `add !== b`. One is a function, the other is an object instance.

Answer (score 1):

- In the first example, you're creating a new object with `add` as the
  constructor, and giving it an *own property*.
- In the second example, you're giving the `add` function object an
  *own property*.

So you're doing pretty much the same in both situations. It'd be different if say, you changed the prototype of `add`, then you'd be making said property 'inheritable' throughout all the objects created with `new add()`.

---

```
function add() {
    this.name = 'suresh';
    this.lastname = 'kumar';
}

var b = new add();

// Adds property to the new b object, whose constructor is add.
// Only b will have this property.
b.city = 'coimbatore';

// Adds property ONLY to the function object.
// Objects created with add as a constructor won't 'inherit' it
// Only `add` will have this property (although in this case,
// b has a property named the same way, with the same value,
// but they are own properties of each object).
add.city = 'coimbatore';

// Adds property to add's prototype. Objects created with `add`
// as a constructor will inherit it. ( for instance `var z =  new add()` )

add.prototype.hello = 'there';

console.log(b.hello); // 'there'

var c = new add();
console.log(c.hello); // 'there'

// Adds own property to the `c` object.
// Only c will have this property:

c.myVeryOwnProperty = 'yeaah!';
console.log( c.myVeryOwnProperty ); // 'yeaah!'
console.log( b.myVeryOwnProperty ); // undefined
console.log( add.myVeryOwnProperty ); // undefined

// Now, check this out:

// True, because you set the properties directly on the object
console.log( add.hasOwnProperty('city') ); // true
console.log( b.hasOwnProperty('city') ); // true
console.log( c.hasOwnProperty('myVeryOwnProperty') ); // true

// False, because these objects got the `hello` property
// through add's prototype
console.log( b.hasOwnProperty('hello') ); // false
console.log( c.hasOwnProperty('hello') ); // false
```

Comment: Function object ? What default properties it has. Does it have arguments,name ?

Comment: Yeah, functions are objects, and you can treat them like so. Try `add.name` and it will log `'add'`. They also have some other properties, like `length`, which indicates how many formal arguments the function has.

Comment: So  function body is function constructor so properties present in function body becomes the properties of the "var b=new add()".

Comment: Yeah, only the properties set with `this.property` (inside of the function body), though, or through `add.prototype.property`. If you declared a variable with `var`, inside of `add`'s function body, then that wouldn't become a property of objects created with `new add()`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to demonstrate the difference is by removing one of the lines from your example and looking at what we have

```
function add() {
    this.name = 'suresh';
    this.lastname = 'kumar';
}

var b = new add();
// b.city = 'coimbatore'; // this line removed

add.city = 'coimbatore';
```

Now, what is `b.city`?

```
b.city; // undefined
```

No future instance will have a city property either, so it's not just the order of setting that causes `b` not to have it.

```
var c = new add();
c.city; // undefined
```

This means setting a property on the constructor has no effect on the objects it constructs (with some special exceptions, such as the *prototype* property)

---

This is happening because the `add` constructor is it's own *Object* and objects created by `new add` are *instances of* `add`, so inherit from `add.prototype`, not `add` itself.

---

If you want every instance to inherit something and it's okay if they're not *own properties*, then you can add them to the prototype of the constructor. Be careful if you're adding *Objects* though as any changes to them will modify for all instances.

Consider

```
add.prototype.city = 'coimbatore';
b.city; // "coimbatore"
// and don't have to worry if you change it on an instance
b.city = 'fizz';
c.city; // "coimbatore"
```

And the danger I warned about with *Objects*

```
add.prototype.foo = {bar: 'baz'};
b.foo.bar; // "baz"
// but have to worry if you change it on an instance
b.foo.bar = 'fizz';
c.foo.bar; // "fizz", it got changed too :(
```